# Как рассчитать скользящую корреляцию между 2 числовыми рядами?

Tags: статистика, статический-анализ

Есть два числовых ряда: цена золота и изменение реальной процентой ставки в США за последние четыре года.

Нужно расчитать 30-ти дневную скользяую корреляцию т.е. на каждый день расчитать корреляцию за предыдущие 30 дней.

Т.к. распределение цены золота и реальной процентой ставки не нормальное, следовательно напрямую расчитывать корреляцию нельзя.

Для золота выход простой: нужно расчитать однодневную доходность и распределение этих значений уже приблизится к нормальному.

Но что в таком случае нужно расчитывать для реальной процентой ставки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для анализа двух нестационарных временных рядов в общем случае корректно анализировать не корреляцию, а коинтеграцию между рядами.
См., например, вот тут:
https://golos.io/ru--finansy/@sagaan/kak-pravilno-vyyavlyat-vzaimosvyazi-v-ekonomike-klyuchevoe-slovo-kointegraciya